# Pass PHP function through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, variables

I don't understand JavaScript or ajax very well and I am trying to pass a php variable through a function to a php page, and none of the methods Im trying are working.

It is a php page with a rating function in javascript, which connects to a php page that saves the data to a database.

This is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".stars").rating({    
        php: 'upload/admin/php/manager.php', 
        skin: 'upload/skins/skin.png', 
        showtext: false,  
        debug : true,
    }); 
});
```

Then this is the form:

```
<div class="stars" data-id="accessibility2" data-title="short item description" prime="<? echo $prime; ?>"></div>
```

I am calling it on the php page with:

```
$prime = $_GET["prime"];
```

and entering it into a database with the other form info, but it never works.

Comment: have you tried ajx and jquery post() function ??

Comment: Sounds like a plugin you're using.  It will have its own specification.  Citing that and looking at what it sends will be helpful.  Could be as easy as `$_POST['prime']`... but without the spec, no one will know.

Comment: It IS a plugin.  But I am not sure what you are suggesting I post on here.  What do you mean "looking at what it sends".  It is this plugin.  http://codecanyon.net/item/skinnable-rating-system-admin-area/3853477

Comment: @Tim it's closed source so it's hard to say why. Can you open developer tools in your browser and see the post data?